# Display text file stopping each line at a given character

Tags: shell, awk, sed, text-processing, cut

I have a text file containing French words, here is an example:

```
hackeur -euse (n.m/f.)
huppe (n. f.) 
huque (n. f.) 
hure (n. f.)
```

I would like to display the file, stopping each line when the pattern  `(` is detected. The expected output is:

```
hackeur -euse
huppe
huque
hure
```

I would like to do this with command line. Is it feasable ?

Comment: What did you try on your own?

Comment: @Inian Nothing, I'm stucked at searching a solution on internet. I'm even not sure this is feasable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `awk` idea using  `(` as a field delimiter:

```
$ awk -F' [(]' '{print $1}' french.dat
hackeur -euse
huppe
huque
hure
```

A couple more quick-n-dirty ideas ...

`cut`:

```
$ cut -d'(' -f1 french.dat
hackeur -euse
huppe
huque
hure
```

**NOTE:** this will leave a trailing blank, which can be trimmed off via other commands (eg, `sed`)

`sed` and a capture group:

```
$ sed -En 's/^(.*) \(.*/\1/p' french.dat
hackeur -euse
huppe
huque
hure
```

**NOTE:** this assumes a single occurrence of  `(`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on GNU `grep`

```sh
grep -Po '^.*?(?= \()' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can use `match()` and `substr()` functions, if you want `each line when the pattern` ( `is detected`

```
awk 'match($0, /[(]/) {print substr($0, 1,RSTART-1)}' file
hackeur -euse
huppe
huque
hure
```